# Using nextInt with arrays (beginning java)

Tags: java, arrays

For a programming assignment we have to create array methods that carry out different tasks.
For this one, I had to return the second largest element in the array.

Below is my method body. An error came up on the values[i]=values.nextInt(); line saying "cannot invoke nextInt() on the array type int[]" The rest of it should work fine (as far as I can tell..I have no other errors but I haven't tested it yet) Any ideas on how I could fix the nextInt error?

Thanks!

```
     public int returnSecondLargest(){
     int secondLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
     int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
     for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
         values[i] = values.nextInt();
         if (largest < values[i]) {
             secondLargest = largest;
             largest = values[i];
         }
         if (secondLargest < values[i] && largest != values[i])
             secondLargest = values[i];
        }
     return secondLargest;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public int returnSecondLargest(){
     int secondLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
     int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
     for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
         if(values[i] > values[i+1]){
             int temp = values[i];
             values[i] =values[i + 1];
             values[i+1] = temp;
         }
    }
    return values[values.length - 2];
}
```

Comment: this works great thank you! I just took out the 2 & 3 lines initializing secondLargest and largest because they're not needed and I replaced it with int temp;

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Arrays class and sort an array. In this case it will be an ascending order so you want the 2nd to last thing in array so thats why I called the index on array - array.length-2.  If I had called array.length-1 you would just get the last index which is the biggest number in array. With this method you can just pass in your array into parameters.

```
public int secondLargest(int[] array){
        Arrays.sort(array);

        return array[array.length-2];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, values is an array (not the Array class). It has no methods such as nextInt.

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of
>   a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is
>   created.

I like to think of it as a primitive type (its not), as both arrays and primitive types do not have methods to manipulate them, but have classes/objects that contain methods that can.

A method to return the second largest could be implemented just by removing that line, I'm not sure why you had it there.